# Boundary value problem with a DiracDelta

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions, discontinuity

It seems that Mathematica can solve an initial value problem with a `DiracDelta`, but not a boundary value problem with a `DiracDelta`. Is there a workaround?

Consider for example a differential equation with this form:

```
f''[x]+x f'[x]== x^2 DiracDelta[x-1]
```

in the range `0,<x<10` with the boundary conditions `f[0]=0`, `f[10]=1`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by can't solve? I do get a solution. Also, for a one-dimensional case, there is no difference between boundary conditions and initial conditions.

Comment: @Roderic Maybe I chose the wrong example that can be solved with `DSolve`, but I need a numerical solution and `NDSolve` does cannot solve the above equation as the image shows.

Comment: right ```DSolve``` does give a solution in terms of ```Erf``` and ```HeavisideTheta```.  I don't know much about the numerical algorithms, sorry.

Comment: Manual shooting method?

Comment: @MichaelE2 could you post an answer? I am not good with numerical methods either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@MichaelE2 gave the idea to use a shooting method, because NDSolve is only able to handle initial value problems involving `DiracDelta`

First solve the problem with a parametric slope `f'[0]==fs0`

```
F = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[x] + x f'[x] == x^2*DiracDelta[x - 1],
f[0] == 0, f'[0] == fs0}, f , {x, 0, 10}, fs0]
```

Now choose `fs0` to fullfill the second boundary condition `f[10]==1`

```
sol = FindRoot[F[fs0][10] == 1, {fs0, 1}]

Plot[F[fs0 /. sol][x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: aargh, I was just entering my answer when yours appeared. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry

Comment: No problem.  ;-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't know `NDSolve` can handle `DiracDelta` when dealing with IVP of ODE! Further test shows this seems to be related to the setting `Method -> "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> True`, which is added since _v9_.

Answer (score 6):

Replacing `DiracDelta` by its approximation in the weak topology helps:

```
s = NDSolve[{f''[x] + x f'[x] == x^2 *0.01/Pi/((x - 1)^2 + 0.01^2),
f[0] == 0, f[10] == 1}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[f[x] /. s, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Rigorously saying, we replace the δ-distribution which is not associated with any usual function  by the distribution associated with a usual function `0.01/Pi/((x - 1)^2 + 0.01^2)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f, x];
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[x] + x f'[x] == 
     x^2 DiracDelta[x - 1], f[0] == 0, f'[0] == p}, 
   f, {x, 0, 10}, {p}];

FindRoot[psol[p][10] == 1, {p, 0.2}]
bvpsol = psol[p] /. %;
(*  {p -> 0.274728}  *)

bvpsol[{0, 10}]
% - {0, 1}
(*
{0., 1.}
{0., -1.44329*10^-15}
*)
```